# Изменять существующий XML Файл при помощи C#

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток !
Подскажите пожалуйста как изменять существующий XML Файл при помощи C# ?
К примеру есть такой XML файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataSet>
<Table>
<Temperature>59</Temperature>
<Humidity>52 %</Humidity>
<WindSpeed>7 м/c</WindSpeed>
<Condition>Scattered Showers</Condition>
<additionally>0</additionally>
</Table>
</DataSet>
```

В нём я хочу изменить данные, как это правильней реализовать ?
Заранее благодарю !

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простейший способ --

- создать XmlDocument
- загрузить через LoadXml()
- выполнить операции над деревом
- Сохранить через Save()

Примерно так:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlstring);

XmlElement newElem = doc.CreateElement("new");
newElem.InnerText = "text";
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newElem);

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("data.xml", settings);
doc.Save(writer);
```

Если же XML ооочень большой и важна скорость обработки -- то лучше обрабатывать поток через XmlReader + XmlWriter, ставить if на появление интересующих конструкций и вставлять/пропускать элементы.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью Linq to XML:

```
    XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(pathToXml);

    xmlFile.Root
        .Element("Table")
        .Element("Temperature")
        .SetValue(newValue);

    xmlFile.Save(pathToXml);
```